# how to loop over multiple lists in python

Tags: python, list, loops

Below, set1, set2, set3 are lists with len(setn) =len(index). I want to loop over each of these lists (setn) as follows,

```
index = range(10)
set1 = range(10,20)
set2 = range(30,40)
set3 = range(40,50)
listset = [set1, set2, set3]
for i in listset:
  for k, j in zip(index, i):
     print k, j

Result:
0 s
1 e
2 t
3 1
0 s
1 e
2 t
3 2
0 s
1 e
2 t
3 3
```

How can I get a result that prints the each element of "index, set1" (as given below),followed by "index, set2", followed by "index, set3".

```
0 10
1 11
2 12
3 13
4 14
5 15
6 16
7 17
8 18
9 19
and so on...
```

Comment: your for loop works to get the expected result, what are you searching for?

Comment: Sorry but I think that my editing of the question solved your problem... So it was just a typo with the quotes.

Comment: The correctly edited post (replacing the literals `'set1'`etc with the real variable names `set1` (note no more apostrophes, produces the wished output ;-)

Comment: For a moment I thought I had destroyed the question :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no very compact inline answer ;-)

Comment: I actually edited it because some quotes were missing: syntax error. So there was a typo in the typo :) BTW not sure that the answers below really see the point.

Comment: @Dilettant Au contraire `_ = [print(i, n) for i, n in itertools.chain(enumerate(s1), enumerate(s2), enumerate(s3))]`

Comment: ok, so maybe the question is still bad.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh but given the questions "level" your one-liner is somehow inline, but shouldn't one add "do not try this at home ? A list comprehension and assignment with the print as side effect, two red herrings in one line ;-) - but you are right, i meant in"place" compact answer by removing only 6 characters from the question ... and my fingers typed inline

Comment: @Dilettant I agree totally.  Unacceptable in the real world, but never say never ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to combine `enumerate` and `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain
s1 = range(10)
s2 = range(10, 20)
s2 = range(20, 30)
c = chain(enumerate(s1), enumerate(s2), enumerate(s3))
for i, n in c:
    print(str(i).ljust(4), n)
```

Comment: Could you please give a brief explanation of how this chain works. For example, I tried "for i in c:   print i", which outputs the same results with a different formatting. So what is the difference between print i, n and simply print i. How do I get print only the first (or any specific) set (s1, s2) from c?

Comment: @gogo We give `chain` an arbitrary number of iterators.  `chain` returns a generator that yields values from those iterators in order to exhaustion. So we first get all the things from `s1` then from `s2` and so on. If you only want `s1` and `s2` from `c` then you have to either check every value to see if it is the first value of `s3` or exclude `s3` from the definition of `c`

Comment: @gogo If you look at the output of `list(enumerate([10, 11, 12]))`, you'll see that it produces `[(0, 10), (1, 11), (2, 12)]`.  What enumerate does is replace each element in a sequence with a tuple of `(index, element)` where `index` is the index of that element in the list,  So when you write `for i in c:`, `i` is equal to those tuples.  When you write `for i, n in c:`, it automatically unpacks the tuples so that `i` is the index and `n` is the element .

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate set1, 2 and 3 together, then use itertools.cycle(index) and zip the resulting two things together:
    `zip(itertools.cycle(index), set1 + set2 + set3)`